# Meteorite Not Installing on OS 10.9

Tags: macos, node.js, meteor, osx-mavericks, meteorite

I'm trying to install Meteorite on OS 10.9 using NPM but am having some issues. From the install log, it appears as if everything went swimmingly after running:

```
sudo -H npm install -g meteorite
```

Unfortunately, after I attempt to run

```
mrt add router
```

for example, I get the following:

```
$ mrt
zsh: command not found: mrt
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Expect all kinds of problems when you install meteorite with `sudo`. You've probably just installed the package for the root user, so now each time you want to use it you should run `sudo mrt` instead of `mrt`. Try running the installation command again without `sudo -H`.

Comment: `sudo mrt` has the same result: `sudo: mrt: command not found`. Also, running without `sudo` produces tons of errors within NPM.

Comment: Try running:

    `npm list -g | grep meteorite`,
    `sudo npm list -g | grep meteorite`.
    
Do you see `meteorite` listed in output of any of these commands?

Comment: It seems like npm is aware of meteorite installed as version 0.6.16. So then it must be an issue of `PATH`? Where could it be installing if not in my `/usr/local/bin`?

Answer (score 0):

Is `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH`?

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Run that in your shell and try again. If it works, you should ideally add it to your shells' startup file (which is probably `~/.bash_profile`).

Comment: After running `echo $PATH` it seems that it is already in my PATH `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

Comment: @Michael are you using the official Node, or one installed by something like Homebrew?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I compiled directly from source.

Comment: What does `which mrt` give you?  I suspect the symlinks didn't get setup correctly so `mrt` isn't actually in a directory in your path.  For reference, when I run `which mrt` on my osx 10.9 machine I get `/usr/local/bin/mrt`.

Comment: @Michael if it's an option, try running the [binary installer](http://nodejs.org/download/) to (re-)install Node.

Comment: @alanning When I run `which mrt` I get `command not found`. Robert, do you mean the universal installer or from source for my specific operating system?

Comment: `which mrt` gives `command not found` so `mrt` is not in a location that is on your path.  You'll need to find out where npm installed meteorite to and then symlink it into a location on your path.  The thing is, you'll probably have this problem with anything you `sudo npm` so the best solution is to clean up your npm so that you don't have to use sudo.